# How shouldi avoid the CS0120 error in my code?

Tags: c#

First i'll give you a run around my code,
I have a class that stores some data :

```
public class Balta
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int raza;
        public int cantApa;
        public int id;
        public int intersect;
        public Balta(int xs, int ys, int r, int cApa, int ids, int intersctt)
        {
            x = xs;
            y = ys;
            raza = r;
            cantApa = cApa;
            id = ids;
            intersect = intersctt;
        }        
    }
```

Secondly I have a class that makes a list of that data and stores it acordingly,also i intend to do some operations with that data once i get rid of this pesky error.

```
public class Baltile
    {
        public int n;
        List<Balta> balti = new List<Balta>();

        public void populate(Balta balta)
        {
            int unitId = balta.id;
        if (balti.Any(Balta => Balta.id == balta.id))
        {
            int pos = balti.FindIndex(Balta => Balta.id == balta.id);
            balti[pos] = balta;
        }
        else if (balti.Any(Balta => Balta.cantApa == -1) && !balti.Any(Balta => Balta.id == unitId)) 
        {                    
                int pos = balti.FindIndex(Balta => Balta.cantApa == -1);
                balti[pos] = balta;                                                             
        }
        else //daca nu inseamna ca aduaugi balta la lista
        {
            balti.Add(balta);
        }
        }
    }
```

And main looks something like this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {             
            Baltile balti = new Baltile();
            while (true)
            {
              "data input block"
              for (int i = 0; i < unitCount; i++)
              {
               "more data input"    
               if (i>2)
               {
                Balta balta = new Balta(x, y, radius, extra, unitId, 0);
                Baltile.populate(balta);//the CS0120 error is here
               }
             }
           }
         }
```

So CS0120 tells me this An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.This means main is static so i cant call a non static method if i understood right ? Declaring everything static will give even more errors.

How should i go around this ? I cant seem to figure out how to make my code work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
Baltile.populate(balta);
```

and `Baltile` being a class name, this would require `populate()` to be a static method.

[As per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120), the full error message is

> Compiler Error CS0120
>
> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'member'

This tells you to use an object instead of a class. And it seems you already have an object called `balti` that serves this purpose. So use

```
balti.populate(balta);
```

instead. Now you call the `populate()` method on an instance (an object) instead of the class.