# Dynamic Query Builder for ASP.Net-MVC - Using jQuery QueryBuilder, DataTables, and dynamic-linq-query-builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatables, jquery-query-builder

I'm trying to accomplish the following Tasks:

1. Create a visual expression/ query builder for ASP.NET-MVC.
2. Pass the resulting query to DataTables.

This question is about Task 1 as that's where I'm stuck. I have posted Task 2 to provide more background information.

To achieve Task 1 I'm using the jQuery QueryBuilder - a jQuery plugin to create user friendly queries. On the QueryBuilder website there is a listing for .NET under the Backends section (https://querybuilder.js.org/#backends). They recommend to use the dynamic-linq-query-builder by Castle-it (https://github.com/castle-it/dynamic-linq-query-builder).

**Here is my issue:**

The dynamic-linq-query-builder all seems to be built with static classes. I want to retrieve the data from my database but from my research online I'm not able to initiate a dbcontext within a static class.

Dynamic-linq-query provides a PersonBuilder class to deserialize a JSON data and they include a TestData string:

```
 public static class PersonBuilder
            {
                public static List<PersonRecord> GetPeople()
                {
                    var result = new List<PersonRecord>();

                    var testData = TestData;

                    var personRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonRecord>>(testData);

                    return personRecords;

                }

                private static string TestData
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return @"
                                [
            {
                ""FirstName"": ""Jane"",

                ""LastName"": ""Hansen"",
                ""Birthday"": ""1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00"",
                ""Address"": ""P.O. Box 492, 4607 Tempus, Rd."",
                ""City"": ""Polatlı"",
                ""State"": ""Ankara"",
             ...
             ...
             ...
```

Then in the HomeController they are using the following to filter the query:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(FilterRule obj)
{
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    var people = PersonBuilder.GetPeople().BuildQuery(obj).ToList();

    return Json(people);


}
```

And here is their QueryBuilder implementation and jQuery logic to read out the results.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        var tableData = [];

        var filterDefinition = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.FilterDefinition);
        var customFilters = {
            condition: 'AND',
            rules: []
        };
        var jqueryQueryBuilder = $('#jquery-query-builder');
        var jqueryQueryBuilderDom = jqueryQueryBuilder.queryBuilder({
            plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors', 'filter-description'],
            //allow_groups: 0,
            allow_empty: true,
            filters: filterDefinition,
            rules: customFilters,
            icons: {
                add_group: 'fa fa-plus-square',
                add_rule: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                remove_group: 'fa fa-minus-square',
                remove_rule: 'fa fa-minus-circle',
                error: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                sortable: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle'
            }
        });

        var convertArraysToCommaDelimited = function(obj) {
            if (obj != null) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
                    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( obj.value ) === '[object Array]' ) {
                        obj.value = obj.value.join(", ");
                    }
                }
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("rules") && obj.rules != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.rules.length; i++) {
                        convertArraysToCommaDelimited(obj.rules[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var getRules = function() {
            try {
                var res =  jqueryQueryBuilder.queryBuilder('getRules');
                convertArraysToCommaDelimited(res);
                return res;
            } catch (ex) {
                //console.log(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        var buildTable;
        var filterData = function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "../Home/Index",
                data: JSON.stringify(getRules()),
                success: function (returnPayload) {
                    tableData = returnPayload;
                    buildTable();
                    console && console.log ("request succeeded");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console && console.log ("request failed");
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",            
                processData: false,
                async: true
            });
        }



        $('#applyFilter').on('click', function() {
            filterData();
        });
        buildTable = function() {
            var tbody = $('#data-table tbody'),
                props = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Birthday", "Age", "Address", "City", "State", "ZipCode"];
            tbody.empty();
            $.each(tableData, function(i, reservation) {
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
                    $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
                });
                tbody.append(tr);
            });
        };

        filterData();

    });

</script>
```

You'll notice that they've created a buildTable function. Later I would like to replace this with a DataTable implementation.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried to initiate a dbcontext with LINQ in the PersonBuilder class. The issue is that this class was static. I simply removed the static definition of the PersonBuilder class. Here is my implementation:

```
public List<PersonRecord> GetPeople()
        {
            IQueryable<PersonRecord> query = DbContext.PersonRecord;


            var data = query.Select(asset => new Asset
            {
                data1 = PersonRecord.data1,
                data2 = PersonRecord.data2,
                ...
                ...

            }).ToList();

            return data;
        }
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the HomeController is now throwing the following error:

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field,
>   method, or property 'member'

At the following line:

```
var people = PersonBuilder.GetPeople().BuildQuery(obj).ToList();
```

Not quite sure how to get around this since it seems the entire library is built with static classes?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're defining `GetPeople()` as non-static method inside `PersonBuilder` class which marked as `static`. As noted in [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members), static classes must contain only static members, including static methods (see the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783828/why-cant-static-classes-have-non-static-methods-and-variables)).

The [CS0120 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120) indicates that you should use either static class with static method, or non-static class' instantiated constructor as object. If you want to use non-static method, the class should not marked as `static`, also the class constructor must be instantiated first before the method can be accessed:

```
public class PersonBuilder
{
    public List<PersonRecord> GetPeople()
    {
        IQueryable<PersonRecord> query = DbContext.PersonRecord;

        var data = query.Select(asset => new Asset
        {
           data1 = PersonRecord.data1,
           data2 = PersonRecord.data2,
           // other stuff

        }).ToList();

        return data;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(FilterRule obj)
{
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    var personBuilder = new PersonBuilder(); // add constructor initialization first
    var people = personBuilder.GetPeople().BuildQuery(obj).ToList();

    return Json(people);
}
```

Related issue:

[How shouldi avoid the CS0120 error in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381416/how-shouldi-avoid-the-cs0120-error-in-my-code)

Comment: hello, how would I handle this in a generic way, i.e. if I didnt know my Person type and simply was trying to load the objects to the builder. Specifically speaking, I have CSV files I am loading and converting to List. Another question, who can I `access the linq query Posted back` from the user